# Convert List to generic list

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, windows-phone-8, json.net

I'm trying to convert json data into generic list

```
string result = e.Result;
JObject o = JObject.Parse(result);
var results = o["Data"];
List<Data> _lst = results.ToList();
```

but list conversion it's showing error

```
 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<PhoneApp2.Employee.CandidateManager.Data>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Comment: You have to show how to get a `Data` instance from `JToken` using `Select`

Comment: Can you also show the json you get in `result`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should convert `JToken` to `Data`:

```
Data CreateData(JToken token)
{
    // some code for creating Data from token.
}
```

Then you can use it:

```
var _lst = results.Select(CreateData).ToList();
```

**EDIT**

For example your `Data` class looks like this:

```
class Data
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int SomeValue {get; set; }
}
```

Let `token` have `SomeValue` and `Name` keys.

Your `CreateData` method will be

```
Data CreateData(JToken token)
{
    return new Data
    {
        Name = token.Value<string>("Name"),
        SomeValue = token.Value<int>("SomeValue")
    }
}
```

Comment: can u explain with example

Comment: Show string when you have a exception.

Comment: g8 job buddy.tenkew so much